# How to apply regex to unicode

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I'm trying to `match` a regex to unicode. It should just pick up the digits inside the brackets. Pattern:

```
^.*?\([^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\).*$
```

But it doesn't work on this unicode:

> 152.6\xa0MiB\xa0(160008742\xa0Bytes)

[Reference](http://regex101.com/r/vK9pA3/1)

Isn't the unicode flag sufficient?

PS: expected group match is `160008742`

Comment: `re.compile(r"^.*?\([^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\).*$", re.UNICODE).match(u"152.6\xa0MiB\xa0(160008742\xa0Bytes)")` matches successfully for me (Python 2.7 and 3.3).

Comment: @ArminRigo I still get `>>> re.compile(r"^.*?\([^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\).*$", re.UNICODE).match(u"152.6\xa0MiB\xa0(160008742\xa0Bytes)").group()`
 `u'152.6\xa0MiB\xa0(160008742\xa0Bytes)'`

Comment: @ArminRigo I added that it should only match the digits inside the brackets

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie, unless `\xA0` is a literal non-breaking space, then there are two runs of digits inside the parentheses.  Could you clarify the string that you're trying to match?

Comment: @MikeSamuel @ArminRigo Yes, sorry, that's a space. I'm expecting `160008742`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing the `.group()` with `.group(1)`.  The latter is what you are looking for.  The former returns the whole text that matched, as documented.

Comment: go figure; I was using `.group()[1]`